# Add auto fill suggestion programmatically in Excel using EPPlus and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus-4

I am trying to create an `excel` with auto fill suggestion for the cells of a specific column.

Let in my generated excel there is a column called "Name". When user write name they will get some suggestion added by me.

So, I want to add auto fill suggestion programmatically using `c#` and `epplus`.

Comment: Do you refer to Dropdown list like [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-drop-down-list-7693307a-59ef-400a-b769-c5402dce407b)? If true, you can refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210584/excel-epplus-net-library-advanced-dropdown-list-validation)

Comment: I have solved my problem using your help. Thanks.

Comment: One more thing. Is it possible when i type into a cell give me suggestion from drop down ?