# Create a column dropdown in EPPlus

Tags: epplus, epplus-4

I have everything else worked out but I want to put a drop down on a cell (range of cells) so that users are forced to select from the list.

I've tried this:

```
                var dd = worksheet.Cells[5, 3, row, 3].DataValidation.AddListDataValidation() as ExcelDataValidationList;
                dd.AllowBlank = true;
                //Add list here
```

But I can't find any method or property that allows me to link the list.

How is this done? I can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel & EPPlus .NET library: Advanced DropDown list validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210584/excel-epplus-net-library-advanced-dropdown-list-validation)

Comment: won't this answer work for you?

Comment: It will, but the api directly allows you to pass an array directly instead of having to have additional sheets which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way is to use the Formula.Values.Add:

```
                dd = worksheet.Cells[5, 4, row, 4].DataValidation.AddListDataValidation() as ExcelDataValidationList;
                dd.AllowBlank = true;
                dd.Formula.Values.Add("Yes");
                dd.Formula.Values.Add("No");
```